# agent connected is automatically getting false

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-ecs

I am using EC2 Linux + Networking type ecs cluster , there are many ec2 instances , in some of them agent connected is getting false and number of container in that particular instance is also 0 , i could not understand the issue and how to overcome this problem .

Comment: Have you tried SSHing into one of the instances that isn't connecting and checking the logs at /var/logs/ecs?

Comment: in such case even i can not ssh to the instance